# How to edit a multi-page PDF in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have an exam paper scanned and saved as a PDF and I'm supposed to check it (correcting and giving marks). However, I lost the original hardcopy of this exam paper and I only have the scanned version in PDF. I cannot print this PDF as well since the area where I live is sealed due to covid-19.

The only solution I could think of is as follows:

1. putting tick marks, grades, and numbers in my own handwriting on a blank paper then scanning it.
2. Opening the PDF in Photoshop and place the tick marks and grades on the exam paper.
3. Exporting the file as PDF and emailing it to my boss.

But for some reason Photoshop only allows you to work on a single PDF page at a time and then saving it individually, and this would make my task take ages.

Could I open and edit all the pages in the PDF simultaneously and then save them all into one PDF file again?

Comment: Do you have access to Adobe Acrobat (Pro) and/or InDesign?

Comment: You are using a programme (Photoshop) which is not designed to edit PDFs even though it can open one and save out to the format. As stated you need a PDF editor like the parent software Acrobat - there are others available though, like PDFelement available in the Apple App Store.

Answer (score 4):

Lucky for you (and all future people who find this question on google like I did) there is a built in system in photoshop to do exactly what you need without any other PDF specific software.

This process is copied from this article: https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-create-a-multi-page-pdf-in-photoshop/

As a note, my transcribed process may be outdated as I am using Photoshop CS3.

1. Open all of the pages of the pdf you intend to edit in photoshop.
2. Save each page of the pdf as a separate photoshop document
   (.PSD)
3. Make any edits you wish on any individual page and save the edits to that page's psd. You should be able to edit these pages as you would any other photoshop document/image.
4. Next go to File > Automate > PDF Presentation
5. Use the provided "browse" option to select all pages of the pdf ( or select "add open files" to automatically open all of the PSDs that you already have open. )
6. Click and drag each file in the list to order them from top to bottom. The top file in the list will be the first page of the generated PDF and the bottom file will be the last page.
7. Before you move on make sure you have the option selected for "Save as: Multi-page document"
8. Select "Save" and you should be guided through selecting a destination folder for your generated pdf and choosing various export settings for your document.

You should also use this process to create multipage PDFs from any combination of PSD files, including combining the pages of multiple PDFs together into one document.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Acrobat, there are markup features and tools within Acrobat itself.

There's no reason to use Photoshop for general editing markup.

Just open the PDF in Acrobat, use the features there and save. -- You can draw, type, highlight, add comments, etc. all in Acrobat.

[**SEE HERE**](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/commenting-pdfs.html) For the Adobe help regarding Acrobat markup.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Acrobat Pro:

Option 1:

1. Backup your PDF file
2. Open the PDF in Adobe Acrobat (Pro)
3. Select the page, right click, edit in Photoshop
4. Do your edits in Photoshop
5. Save the image (you might have to merge the layers first)
6. Return to Acrobat to find the updated image in place
7. Repeat for the following pages

Option 2:

1. Backup your PDF file
2. Open the PDF in Photoshop
3. Select all pages, set size and resolution
4. Do your edits
5. Save the images with a name keeping them in order
6. Open Adobe Acrobat
7. Select `Tools -> Create PDF -> Multiple files -> Combine files` (my program is not in English, so take into account possible naming differences)
8. Select your files / drag your files in
9. Make sure they are in order and check the Options settings.
10. Press Combine.

Comment: If one has **Acrobat Pro** you can *add markup directly in Acrobat*. There's absolutely no reason to edit images with Photoshop.

Comment: Yea. I think the `Fill & Sign` tools should do everything OP needs right in Acrobat Pro.

Comment: My mistake for assuming what the OP needs - but as he suggested that he needed to write the corrections in his _own handwriting_, and then scan them – I assumed that he actually needed his handwriting to show on the corrected paper.